# Know if Windows 10 device supports pen

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

In my C# UWP app I'm trying to detect whether a devices has pen support or not to decide whether to show a button, but I can't find anything about it in the official documentation, do anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Input: Device capabilities sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-device-capabilities-31b67745/sourcecode?fileId=43662&pathId=200504530) which provides an example.

Basically you use Windows.Devices.Input to loop through available devices (mouse, pointers etc) and decide if a pen / stylus is present.